# DC Motor will not work. Transistor method nor L293D!

Tags: motor

New to Arduinos and stuff.

I have tried the L293D and the transistor method but the motor just wouldnt work.

I have tested the motor and it definitely is fine.

Below is my layout for this attempt:

Bits used:

- Arduino UNO
- 1N4007 Diode
- PN2222
- 230 ohm resistor

[image]

My sketch is ::

```cpp
int motorPin = 3;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(motorPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  if (Serial.available()) {
    int speed = Serial.parseInt();
    if (speed >= 0 && speed <= 255) {
      analogWrite(motorPin, speed); 
    }
  }
}
```

HELP!!!

Comment: First of all don't power the motor using your Uno's 5V supply.  Motors are notoriously noisy and will almost always cause the Uno to be unstable and reset itself.

Comment: Check your line ending in the serial terminal. If you have anything other than "none" then you'll get your number followed immediately by 0.

Comment: You can sanity check your transistor setup by not controlling the base in software.  Just take your jumper out of pin 3 and manually connect it to 5V and GND.  If you motor doesn't turn then, it has nothing to do with your software.

Comment: use simplest possible code to run the motor ... there is absolutely no reason to have any Serial code in your sketch when testing the motor .... only two commands are needed, pinMode and analogWrite ... both can be in setup()

Comment: Actually you don't even need the pinMode - PWM is an alternative function and not affected by the direction register.

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys. I have tried this setup multiple times but it didn't work. So now I put it together again to try some of the suggestions and it just worked before I could implement any of the above suggestions. I will try now with the L293 and come back.